# What is the difference between an anchor without a hash sign and an anchor with a hash sign?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

According to the [AsciiDoc Syntax Quick Reference](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/syntax-quick-reference/), it appears that inline anchor declarations (and maybe other kinds of anchor declarations, but they are not described?) can take either of the following forms:

- `[[a1]]`
- `[#a2]`

The [documentation explaining the second option](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/syntax-quick-reference/#links) hints that (perhaps?) this form is used (only?) when anchoring text that already has hash signs around it somewhere?  But this is not made explicit.  (Somewhat humorously, "Example 15", which shows examples of (inline) anchors, is not directly linkable.)

[In the wild](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-ee4j/websocket-api/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/WebSocket.adoc), I've also seen explicit anchors defined like this:

```
[[goals]]
= Goals
```

…though it is worth noting that in the [AsciiDoc source code of the AsciiDoc Syntax Quick Reference document itself](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asciidoctor/asciidoc-docs/main/docs/modules/ROOT/pages/syntax-quick-reference.adoc) that form is not used.

Anyway, could such an example be defined equivalently like this?

```
[#goals]
= Goals
```

…If so, why do the two formats exist?

I have stumbled across a section on [block style and attribute shorthand](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/positional-and-named-attributes/#block-style-and-attribute-shorthand) which may hold the answer, suggesting that the practice of using `[[this-form]]` as a way of defining an anchor on, say, a section heading is not as correct as using `[#this-form]`, but I'd like to hear more.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I found my answer.  Using `[[this form]]` as what amounts to an ID declaration is [legacy](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/id/).